# Where would I ask a question about screenshot automation?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, specific-question, site-recommendation

I am searching for a solution that makes an automated screenshot of an AJAX-heavy page 10 seconds after it loaded. But Stack Overflow doesn't seem to be the right site for the question: [Static caching as image of heavy DHTML-Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462069/static-caching-as-image-of-heavy-dhtml-pages)

Where would my question be more appropriate?

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is going to be: nowhere. It is not so much that your question is a bad fit for Stack Overflow, but that it's not a good question at all and wouldn't do any better anywhere else on the network.

Answer (score -2):

This would be https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

for example: [Website or bookmarklet to get a screenshot of a webpage](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/582/website-or-bookmarklet-to-get-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage)

Comment: I disagree that this would be a good question for Web Apps. Your example is a straight-up recommendation request and, if asked today, would be closed.

Comment: You did the same below your SO question. Don't use very old questions as a justification for asking your new question. There is no guarantee that the community hasn't moved on.

Comment: so why is it, that recommendations are not welcome anywhere anymore?